# modify user's UID not updating

Tags: linux, chef-infra

need to modify UID of a specific user so created:

```
#change UID of bob from 555 to 1555
user 'bob' do
  action :modify
  uid 1555
end
```

After the chef-client runs with no errors

```
    Recipe: bob-uid-change::default
  * user[bob] action modify (up to date)
```

The user's ID do not change on /etc/passwd

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Also might want to avoid making an entire cookbook just for `bob-uid-change` that is a bit overkill IMHO.  Might want to redesign your user management so that you just need to change a data bag item or node/role/environment attribute to configure users' uids

Comment: thanks, yes this is an example :)

Comment: cool : ), just making sure. your code should work fine, I have almost the exact same code in my users cookbook.  If I remember correctly it correctly did a UID shift of an existing user in it's test cases, I  _think_  the only difference was that the action wasn't :modify, it was unspecified + there were a bunch of other user attributes being set of course.  This _Should_ work, ubuntu @ chef 12

Comment: just verified that your resource declaration _should_ work. The modify action does indeed support and perform uid modifications in my tests

Answer (score 0):

Modify will not work if the user (bob) is currently logged in and using the system, i.e. if there are any active processes for bob.

However, if I remember correctly, chef will bomb out if it can't modify the user due to an active process in their name... instead of silently moving on without updating the user as is with this case.  It's worth a check to make sure you aren't logged in as bob anywhere first though